# Typescript: Can I use prop foo string union to define prop bar map w/foo strings as keys?

Tags: typescript

Wasn't sure how to word this.

```
type FooType = Record<string, number>;
type BarType = Record<string, string>;

type PossibleTypes = "Foo" | "Bar";

type TypeMap = {
  Foo: FooType;
  Bar: BarType;
}

type FProps<?> = {
  type: PossibleTypes
  data: TypeMap[?]
}

function F ({ type, data }: FProps<?>) {
  return { type, data }; 
}

const {type, data} = F({ type: "Foo", data: { Foo: 42 } });

data.Foo = "Baz" //type error
```

I want to ensure the last line would throw a type error *without* having to explicitly type `data`. Is there a way to do this so that the value of the param `type` is used to defined the type of the `data` param?

I tried some generics, but I either was not doing it correctly or was going down the wrong path. In the above code I had tried `FProps<PossibleTypes>` then `type FProps<T>` and `data: TypeMap[T]` with error `TS2536: Type 'T' cannot be used to index type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's modify `FProps` so that it takes `"Foo" | "Bar"` as the generic type.

```
type FProps<T extends PossibleTypes> = {
  type: T
  data: TypeMap[T]
}
```

We also need to add a generic type to the function `F` which holds the type of the `type` property of the passed object.

```
function F<T extends PossibleTypes>({ type, data }: FProps<T>) {
  return { type, data }; 
}
```

Now we get an appropriate error.

```
const { type, data } = F({ type: "Foo", data: { Foo: 42 } });

data.Foo = "Baz" // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=77&pln=20&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAKuaBeKAlCBjOAnAEwB4BnYPASwDsBzAGiioFcBbAIwjwD4BuAKFCQoAIQCGeZEPRZchUuWr0oZSrV58BKKAAU4JEhTYAbCJIgko6AETw4VqAB8oVsXiv9NQswFlRYS1AA3nxQsAgAXGFIKPyhrpGuZvwAvhqC0DDaeHBgJESIUBAAHsAQVAQWuvqGJmYkXAHBoemRiCFQBKLAoq0ovmAA2ogAunypfABmTFTYwBRwVLD5hSVlFTp6BsamKPUAFIFQ6Qyd3VDJkZnZuflcAJRB7XgQwEx4i4fHHV2i5zxQYw0uCoZCCRxQJx%205wCMAO4MgkRsCCskO6kUOtkiABYAEzQ5J3DynUQAOlsARcogAXvYAPS0qAAUTw2TwvSEAHIVIoOVAKBYqHBgFBRNUaFRRNsjnB4dAOcx2JwOSSgA)